# Electric potential and fields

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

In electrostatics, what's the importance of potential, why can't I just just talk about electric field and force one charge has? Also besides that it's the negative gradient of electric field, is there any other way to observe and visualize it?

Answer (score 2):

An electric potential is a mathematically convenient scalar field
whose negative-gradient yields the electrostatic field.

You can certainly ignore using an electric potential of an electrostatic field,
but you may be hindering your intuition and your ability to do calculations.

One often visualizes scalar fields topographically,
by their "level surfaces" or "equipotentials".

UPDATE:
An analogous question in mechanics...
"What is the importance of gravitational potential energy, why can't I just talk about gravitational fields and the gravitational force applied to a mass?"

In both cases, one is exploiting a feature that arises from conservative vector fields (vector fields with the additional property of having a zero curl).